# c++ array to vector issue

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, copy

Im  trying to copy an array to a vector, however, when the  data is copied to the vector its different from that of the original array.

```
int arraySize = 640000;

std::vector<unsigned char> vector_buffer;
unsigned char buffer[arraySize];

populateArray(&buffer);

for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
     cout << buffer[i];  // this prints out data


std::copy ( buffer, buffer + arraySize, std::back_inserter(vector_buffer)); 


for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
     cout << vector_buffer[i];  // this prints out different data
```

The data seems to get compressed somehow. Any approach at copying the array to a vector does the same thing.

Im using it to create a video from images. If i use the array data all is well, but if i use the vector data it doesn't work.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: This is most troubling. Is this an output error, or does comparing the buffer and vector byte-to-byte identify differences? If so, what are they? Do they follow any pattern, such as regular offsets or only some values being affected?

Comment: The code as presented should work. Is that the real code that is failing? Are the types of the array and the vector the same? --Note that you can use (and might be more efficient) `vector_buffer.insert( buffer, buffer+arraySize )`, but that is unrelated to the problem at hand.

Comment: Can you try with array_size being 10 or 20 and show us the putput? Also I am not sure unsigned char buffer[arraySize] can compile on all compilers.

Comment: what is signature of `populateArray`?

Comment: Is it `unsigned char **` or `unsigned char *`?

Comment: Could you provide a brief example of the difference in output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The

```
int arraySize = 640000;
```

needs to be `const` in standard C++. g++ allows variable length arrays as a C99-inspired language extension. It's best to turn that extension off. :-)

```
std::vector<unsigned char> vector_buffer;
unsigned char buffer[arraySize];
```

OK when `arraySize` is `const`, but will not compile with e.g. Visual C++ with your original code.

```
populateArray(&buffer);
```

This should most probably be `populateArray(buffer)`, unless you have a really weird declaration of `populateArray`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
     cout << buffer[i];  // this prints out data
```

The above prints the data with no spacing between the elements. Better add some spacing. Or newlines.

```
std::copy ( buffer, buffer + arraySize, std::back_inserter(vector_buffer));
```

Better just use the `assign` method of `std:.vector`, like `vector_buffer.assign( buffer, buffer + arraySize )`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
     cout << vector_buffer[i];  // this prints out different data
```

Again, this displays the elements with no spacing between.

Is the apparent problem there still when you have fixed these things?

If so, then please post also your `populateArray` function.

Comment: +1 for using `assign()`. I suspect that, in OP's code, `vector_buffer` is somehow getting modified between its declaration and the call to `std::copy()`. If possible, even better is to delay the `vector_buffer` construction until `buffer` is ready, and then do `vector_buffer(buffer, buffer + arraySize);` as in @sbi's code.

Answer (score 3):

I can see nothing wrong with your code. The following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const std::size_t arraySize = 640000;

    unsigned char buffer[arraySize];

    for(std::size_t idx = 0; idx < arraySize; ++idx)
        buffer[idx] = idx;

    std::vector<unsigned char> vector_buffer(buffer, buffer + arraySize);
    //std::vector<unsigned char> vector_buffer;
    //std::copy (buffer, buffer + arraySize, std::back_inserter(vector_buffer)); 

    for(std::size_t idx = 0; idx < arraySize; ++idx)
        if( buffer[idx] != vector_buffer[idx] )
        {
            std::cout << "error @" << idx << '\n';
            return 1;
        }
    std::cout << "Ok.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

prints `Ok.` for me. (Even if I use the less-than-optimal way of copying into the vector.)

From the fact that the code you showed wouldn't compile I conclude that you're not showing the real code. Please do so. Somewhere in the differences between your real code and my code must be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a complete compilable program for you.  The code appears fine.  I run it and get expected output.  Perhaps you need to re-check the code you posted against the real code.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

void populateArray(unsigned char* buf, size_t buf_size)
{
    unsigned char* buf_end = &buf[buf_size];
    for( unsigned char c = 'A'; buf != buf_end; c = (c=='Z'?'A':c+1), ++buf )
        *buf = c;
}

int main()
{

    static const int arraySize = 64;

    std::vector<unsigned char> vector_buffer;
    unsigned char buffer[arraySize];

    populateArray(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
             cout << buffer[i];  // this prints out data

    cout << endl;


    std::copy ( buffer, buffer + arraySize, std::back_inserter(vector_buffer)); 


    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
             cout << vector_buffer[i];  // this prints out different data   

    return 0;
}
```